# Input field value + extra value that is toggleable

Tags: jquery

I have input field that already has value, let us call that value: "value0". When user checks a checkbox "1" will appear behind "value". Now input field value should be "value1". When user uncheck checkbox, input field should have value "value0".

```
   $('input#inputfield1').change(function(){
          var yes = '1';
          $("input#answer").val($("input#answer").val()+yes);  
   });
```

How can I make that toggleable? I tried to search online, but couldn't find any clues how to proceed. Am I doing anything right?

**EDIT:** thanks to Utkanos

```
  $('input#inputfield1').change(function(){
          var answer = $("input#answer").val();
          $("input#answer").val(answer+($(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0));  
  });
```

Currently output is value0101010...if user keeps switching between checked and unchecked. IT has to be value0 or value1.

This one worked! Thank you for your assistance! **Any suggestions for better title?**

```
$('input#inputfield1').change(function(){
    var answer = $("input#answer").val();
    $("input#answer").val(answer.substring(0, answer.length - 1)+($(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('input#inputfield1').change(function(){
    var answer = $("input#answer").val();
    $("input#answer").val(answer.substring(0, answer.length - 1)+($(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0));
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Heraclitus!

Answer (score 0):

On the radio check/uncheck use jquery to set the input based on if the box is checked or not.

```
$("input#answer").val('value'+($(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0));
```

Comment: This works thou input is now "value10101010101010" if user keeps checking and unchecking. It has to be "value0" or "value1".

Comment: No reason this should happen. It clearly sets a new value each time, rather than appending. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3kymfrf/)

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".